# Symfony form editAction with fileupload not working because no file

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have create a form with 2 fields, (name and file). I have follow this guide https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html

I have create my CRUD. My addAction is ok. But my edit action is not ok. When i valid the form for juste change the name and not the file (no file on input file) the form send an error "there is no file". How can I do to make editAction working without new file if no change on file ?

I add my project files

ProductController.php EditAction()

```
    /**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing product entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="product_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Product $product)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($product);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AppBundle\Form\ProductType', $product);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('product_edit', array('id' => $product->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('product/edit.html.twig', array(
        'product'     => $product,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

ProductControlle newAction()

```
    /**
 * Creates a new product entity.
 *
 * @Route("/new", name="product_new")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    $product = new Product();
    $form = $this->createForm(
        'AppBundle\Form\ProductType',
        $product,
        array(
            'validation_groups' => array('add')
        )
    );
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($product);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('product_show', array('id' => $product->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('product/new.html.twig', array(
        'product' => $product,
        'form'    => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

My product entity

```
    /**
 * @var int
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;


/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\Type(type="string")
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.", groups={"add"})
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" }, groups={"add"})
 */
private $brochure;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set brochure
 *
 * @param string $brochure
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setBrochure($brochure)
{
    $this->brochure = $brochure;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get brochure
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBrochure()
{
    return $this->brochure;
}
```

My FileUploder (service)

```
private $targetDir;

public function __construct($targetDir)
{
    $this->targetDir = $targetDir;
}

public function upload(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

    $file->move($this->getTargetDir(), $fileName);

    return $fileName;
}

public function getTargetDir()
{
    return $this->targetDir;
}
```

And my BrochureUploadListener.php

```
    private $uploader;
private $fileName;

public function __construct(FileUploader $uploader)
{
    $this->uploader = $uploader;
}

public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $this->uploadFile($entity);
}

public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    $this->uploadFile($entity);
}

public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    if (!$entity instanceof Product) {
        return;
    }

    if ($fileName = $entity->getBrochure()) {
        $entity->setBrochure(new File($this->uploader->getTargetDir().'/'.$fileName));
    }
}

private function uploadFile($entity)
{
    // upload only works for Product entities
    if (!$entity instanceof Product) {
        return;
    }

    $file = $entity->getBrochure();

    // only upload new files
    if ($file instanceof UploadedFile) {
        $fileName = $this->uploader->upload($file);
        $entity->setBrochure($fileName);
    }
}
```

And my services.yml

```
    AppBundle\Service\FileUploader:
    arguments:
        $targetDir: '%brochures_directory%'

AppBundle\EventListener\BrochureUploadListener:
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: preUpdate }
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use vichuploader bundle and it's more simply and ok.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you use

```
$form->isValid()
```

it actually validates

```
@Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.")
@Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" })
```

but you providing string instead of instance of UploadedFile. What you could do is to create validation group to ensure that this assertions would work only when you create new entity:

```
@Assert\NotBlank(message="Please, upload the product brochure as a PDF file.", groups={"add"})
@Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "application/pdf" }, groups={"add"})
```

And then add to your form options inside your addAction following line:

```
'validation_groups' => array('add')
```

So, your form instantiation inside addAction should look like like this:

```
$form = $this->createForm(YourFormType::class, null, array(
    'validation_groups' => array('add')
));
```

Comment: Hi thank you. The validation group is ok. But when I edit only the name I lost the file on entity. :(

Comment: Could you provide us some code depicting your updateAction to gain better understanding what causes the issue?

Comment: I have update my post with my different files, I have remove the header and comment of file because the rendering is not good.